# Is it possible for an undiscovered, large object of the solar system to occult a star on the sky?

Tags: visible-light, astronomy, solar-system

Is it possible for an undiscovered, large object of the solar system to occult a star on the sky? Maybe trying to discover it by gravitational effects is hard but can astronomers obseve a occultation of the light of a star by an undiscovered object of the solar system like they do with extrasolar planets?

Comment: The answer is of course yes. Maybe you could be a bit more specific about what you want to know.

Comment: seems not very probable of detection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occultation#Occultation_by_planets